# Why does clock::is_steady return const bool instead of just bool?

Tags: c++, c++11

Per Table 59 of the C++11 Standard, the *clock*`::is_steady` function returns `const bool` instead of `bool`. Either way, the return type would be an rvalue of built-in type, hence unmodifiable, so `const` appears to add nothing but noise. So why `const bool` instead of simply `bool`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`is_steady` isn't a function. It's a static member. If it weren't `const` you could change it.